# Управление браузером Chrome c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

Нужно получить полное управление браузером через c#

Открывать, закрывать окна

Переходить по ссылкам

Создавать новые профили Chrome

Удалять профили Chrome

Менять размер окна

*Совершать действия на страницах?*

Через что это лучше сделать? Нужно именно управление браузером, другие варианты не подходят.

Answer (score 1):

Есть инструмент для автоматизации работы с браузером. И имя ему Selenium. Ставишь селениум, подключаешь драйвер к хрому и вперед.